# Truncate decimals beyond first positive

Tags: c#, decimal, truncate

C# - truncate decimals beyond first positive

a number is `0.009012`
result should be `0.009`

or is `1.1234` and 'd be `1.1`
or `2.099` ~ `2.09` 
and so on

*in a fast and optimum way*

Comment: Are you going to display these values ? or use them for calculations ?

Comment: This isn't the case, I approciate shortest solution not that by Carra

Comment: You want it fast, using math will be faster than string parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method:

```
private static string RoundSpecial(double x)
{
    string s = x.ToString();
    int dotPos = s.IndexOf('.');
    if (dotPos != -1)
    {
        int notZeroPos = s.IndexOfAny(new[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }, dotPos + 1);
        return notZeroPos == -1 ? s : s.Substring(0, notZeroPos + 1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I'm not sure that it is the fastest and optimal method, but it does what you want.

Second approach is to use `Log10` and `%`:

```
private static double RoundSpecial(double x)
{
    int pos = -(int)Math.Log10(x - (int)x);
    return Math.Round(x - (x % Math.Pow(0.1, pos + 1)), pos + 1);
}
```

Comment: Parsing as a `double` is a great way to get a number with a different number of digits than you wanted.

Comment: @Rawling Thank you. Parsing removed. Any other issues?

Comment: Nope! It matches OP's examples, even if OP has an odd way of rounding :)

Answer (score 3):

Think mathematically, use logarithmus with base 10

this function will just take the first cipher

```
public double RoundOnFirstDecimal(double number)
{
    int shift = -1 * ((int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number)));
    return Math.Floor(number * Math.Pow(10, shift)) / Math.Pow(10, shift);
}
```

But you want to have it this way: (will shift only regarding the decimal fractions, but not full numbers)

```
public double RoundOnFirstDecimal(double number)
{
    int shift = -1 * ((int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(number % 1)));
    return Math.Floor(number % 1 * Math.Pow(10, shift)) / Math.Pow(10, shift) + number - number % 1;
}
```

thats gonna be significantly faster than any regex or looping

Answer (score 0):

You may try regular expression too:

```
decimal d = 2.0012m;            

Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?<num>(0*[1-9]))\d*$");
Match match = pattern.Match(d.ToString().Split('.')[1]);
string afterDecimal = match.Groups["num"].Value; //afterDecimal = 001
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses math instead of string logic:

```
double nr = 0.009012;
var partAfterDecimal = nr - (int) nr;
var partBeforeDecimal = (int) nr;

int count = 1;
partAfterDecimal*=10;
int number = (int)(partAfterDecimal);
while(number == 0)
{
  partAfterDecimal *= 10;
  number = (int)(partAfterDecimal);
  count++;
}

double dNumber = number;
while(count > 0){
 dNumber /= 10.0;
 count--;
}

double result = (double)partBeforeDecimal + dNumber;
result.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the `Math` library:

```
    static double truncateMyWay(double x)
    {
        double afterDecimalPoint = x - (int)x;
        if (afterDecimalPoint == 0.0) return x;
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            int count10 = 1;
            do 
            {
                afterDecimalPoint *= 10;
                count10 *= 10;
                i++;
            } while ((int) afterDecimalPoint == 0);

            return ((int)(x * count10))/((double)count10);
        }
    }
```

Happy Codding! ;-)